# In college and grad-school applications, will the information of self-identified sex information be shared among all reviewers?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, application

Speaking out one's own unusual sexual identity and unusual sex-orientation sometimes take a huge amount of bravery, yet most university applicants in USA are required to disclose that information (there is usually a prefer-not-to-say option).

We must admit that, although all laws and rules disallow discrimination against sexual and cultural minorities, people are still doing this in their heart. For example, it is not unusual to see someone laughing at gay-ish behaviors or a strong English accent.

My question is, will those information be publicly and widely shared among all faculty members who is reviewing that application?

My motivation is: I am more than happy to disclose my unusual orientation, but only to my closest friends (excluding parents) or professional social workers. I want to speak out the truth and I don't want to use the "prefer-not-to-say option". I am also willing to disclose it to a very small professional team of diversity recruiters, but I am definitely uncomfortable to disclose it to an *entire* faculty.

Comment: Would you please clarify what the application is for ?

Comment: @Nobody Mostly grad-school application and I am interested in both College and Grad applications.

Comment: you really have to disclose your sexual orientation (e.g. straight, homosexual), or rather your gender identity (e.g. identifying as female, non-binary)? Because those are two very different things and at least in Europe, asking about the sexual orientation is absolutely not allowed.

Comment: @Sursula I am asked to disclose both.

Comment: I am not familiar with laws in the US, but are you sure that this is legal?

Comment: 1. From what I’ve seen, there is always an option “prefer not to say” in these kind of forms. So I wouldn’t say you are required ro disclose it.

Comment: 2. That being said, the question of who has access to this information is an interesting one and I’m not sure of the answer.

Comment: I suspect that the only colleges that ask about sexual orientation are those that are conservative religious ones. They will also discriminate against anybody non traditional about sex/gender. Can you show an excerpt from the application and a hint about what sort of college this is? Seems very unusual.

Comment: @Buffy Thanks you and leonos are correct that there is a "not-to-say" option. However, I want to speak-up the truth rather than hiding. I am happy to share my private orientation with my closest ones (excluding my parents) and any professional social worker working for the diversity goals. I feel uncomfortable, however, if this part of application is to shared with an entire faculty.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot answer for the US, but in the UK it is common for this sort of question to appear on an application form. However, it usually comes with a disclaimer that your answer will not be seen by the people actually considering your application. The stated purpose of collecting this information is that it will be used, in aggregated form, to assess the overall fairness of the application procedure. If this disclaimer does not appear, I think it would be reasonable to contact the admissions office and check.

Comment: Yes. This used to be the case in USA. Before 2021 there was a section tagged with "will only be shared with diversity staffs" or something like that. However, for now, there is rarely such a disclaimer.

Answer (score 2):

In the US, if you put information on an admissions application then assume that everyone on the admissions committee and those in the administration (likely clerks, office staff) with responsibility for handling applications will see it. It is unlikely to be shared outside the people in the process, but that can't be guaranteed. Unlikely because few would care or even think to do it.

Information that won't be shared should be clearly marked. Some of the information is collected because the government asks for aggregate data on some questions such as race/ethnicity. Most (all?) such questions are marked as optional. For such information, you may assume, that policies are adhered to, though mistakes can be made.

It is even possible that, having seen it, someone might mention it in an interview situation contains parents. It would be inadvertent, probably, but, still, not what you seem to want.

If you want such information closely held then don't put it on such forms, which have a long lifetime.

If you are "forced" in some way to reveal personal things, then I'd suggest that you look elsewhere for your education. You are unlikely to be satisfied with other things occurring at places that would do that.

---

Undergraduate admissions in the US is usually handled by an administrative (Admissions) office. Graduate admission is usually handled by a faculty committee. There are exceptions.